# Function to group by multiple objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python function that groups by based on a single column and calculates the count and mean.

```
def calc_smooth_mean(df, by, on, m):
   mean = df[on].mean()
   agg_value = df.groupby(by)[on].agg(['count', 'mean'])
   counts = agg_value['count']
   means = agg_value['mean']
   smooth = (counts * means + m * mean) / (counts + m)
   return df[by].map(smooth)
```

When I pass more than 1 column to "by", it throws the error "Dataframe object has no attribute map". I tried converting it to list & passed it to the function, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `map` to `apply`, since map is for `Series` and `index` only

We can fix it with `transform`

```
def calc_smooth_mean(df, by, on, m):
   mean = df[on].mean()
   counts = df.groupby(by)[on].transform('count')
   means = df.groupby(by)[on].transform('mean')
   smooth = (counts * means + m * mean) / (counts + m)
   return smooth
```

Comment: When I do, df['A_B_C_encoded'] = calc_smooth_mean(df, by=['A','B','C'], on='Total_GAV', m=10), I get the error "TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index A')". I does not work for single column in "by" as well.

Comment: @user3447653 you can not assign it back into one column A_B_C_encoded

Comment: @user3447653 fix it with transform ~